# Trailing STOPLOSS not triggering in tradingview (pine script)

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I am new to pinescript and trying to code, entry after longcondtion (ema crossover) and strategy exits 100% quantity if initial stoploss triggers. and books 50% quantity at 1st target and remaining 50% quantity should be trailed with supertrend. when supertrend changes direction it should exit with remaining 50%, But it's not exiting remaining 50% quantity even supertrend crosses.  vice versa for short condition

Please suggest me if any one has done similar code, Thanks in advance.

```
if (longCond )
    strategy.entry("BUY",strategy.long)
    
if (shortCond )
    strategy.entry("SELL",strategy.short)


tar=input(defval=30.0,title="TARGET")

sl=input(defval=30.0,title="STOP LOSS")
tar:=tar/syminfo.mintick
sl:=sl/syminfo.mintick

 //adding stoploss and target option
strategy.exit("x1", from_entry="BUY", qty = 50, profit = tar,loss = sl)

strategy.exit("x1", from_entry="SELL",qty = 50, profit = tar,loss = sl)


if strategy.position_size>0 and abs(strategy.position_size)==50 and crossunder(close,atrStop)
    strategy.exit("x2", from_entry="BUY", qty_percent=100)
    

if strategy.position_size<0 and abs(strategy.position_size)==50 and crossover(close,atrStop)
    strategy.exit("x2", from_entry="SELL",qty_percent=100)
```

******complete code as below****

```
//complete code//@version=4
strategy("SLtrail", overlay = true,calc_on_every_tick=true,default_qty_value=100)

quant=input(title="Trade Quantity",defval=50)
// === LOGIC ===
length = input(type=input.integer,defval=20,minval=1,title="Length")
ratio = input(type=input.integer,defval=3,title="Multiplier (3x length, 4x length, etc)",options=[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
longOnly = input(type=input.bool,defval=false,title="Long Only")
fast = ema(hl2,length)
slow = ema(hl2,length * ratio)
plot(fast,linewidth=2,color=color.orange,title="Fast")
plot(slow,linewidth=2,color=color.blue,title="Slow")

longCond = crossover(fast,slow)
shortCond = crossunder(fast,slow)

//length = input(10, "Length", minval = 2)
src = input(close, "Source")
factor = input(3, "Multiplier", minval = 0.25, step = 0.25)
st(src, atrlen, atrfactor) =>
    var max     = src
    var min     = src
    var uptrend = true
    var stop    = 0.0
    atrM        = nz(atr(atrlen) * atrfactor, tr)
    max         := max(max, src)
    min         := min(min, src)
    stop        := nz(uptrend ? max(stop, max - atrM) : min(stop, min + atrM), src)
    uptrend     := src - stop >= 0.0
    if uptrend != nz(uptrend[1], true)
        max    := src
        min    := src
        stop   := uptrend ? max - atrM : min + atrM
    [stop, uptrend]

[atrStop, uptrend] = st(src, length, factor)

plot(atrStop, "Volatility Stop", style=plot.style_stepline, color= uptrend ? #009688 : #F44336)
bool downtrend = (uptrend != true)


if (longCond )
    strategy.entry("BUY",strategy.long)
    
if (shortCond )
    strategy.entry("SELL",strategy.short)


tar=input(defval=30.0,title="TARGET IN POINTS")

sl=input(defval=30.0,title="STOP LOSS IN POINTS")
tar:=tar/syminfo.mintick
sl:=sl/syminfo.mintick

 //adding stoploss and target option
strategy.exit("x1", from_entry="BUY", qty = 50, profit = tar,loss = sl)

strategy.exit("x1", from_entry="SELL",qty = 50, profit = tar,loss = sl)


if strategy.position_size>0 and abs(strategy.position_size)==50 and crossunder(close,atrStop)
    strategy.exit("x2", from_entry="BUY", qty_percent=100)
   

if strategy.position_size<0 and abs(strategy.position_size)==50 and crossover(close,atrStop)
    strategy.exit("x2", from_entry="SELL",qty_percent=100)
    

strategy.exit(id="LX4",from_entry="BUY",qty_percent=100,loss=sl)
strategy.exit(id="LX4",from_entry="SELL",qty_percent=100,loss=sl)
```

Comment: Whole the strategy code can help to find the reason of the problem.

Comment: added complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this version:

```
//@version=4
strategy("SLtrail", overlay = true,calc_on_every_tick=true,default_qty_value=100)

quant=input(title="Trade Quantity",defval=50)
// === LOGIC ===
length = input(type=input.integer,defval=20,minval=1,title="Length")
ratio = input(type=input.integer,defval=3,title="Multiplier (3x length, 4x length, etc)",options=[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
longOnly = input(type=input.bool,defval=false,title="Long Only")
fast = ema(hl2,length)
slow = ema(hl2,length * ratio)
plot(fast,linewidth=2,color=color.orange,title="Fast")
plot(slow,linewidth=2,color=color.blue,title="Slow")

longCond = crossover(fast,slow)
shortCond = crossunder(fast,slow)

//length = input(10, "Length", minval = 2)
src = input(close, "Source")
factor = input(3, "Multiplier", minval = 0.25, step = 0.25)
st(src, atrlen, atrfactor) =>
    var max     = src
    var min     = src
    var uptrend = true
    var stop    = 0.0
    atrM        = nz(atr(atrlen) * atrfactor, tr)
    max         := max(max, src)
    min         := min(min, src)
    stop        := nz(uptrend ? max(stop, max - atrM) : min(stop, min + atrM), src)
    uptrend     := src - stop >= 0.0
    if uptrend != nz(uptrend[1], true)
        max    := src
        min    := src
        stop   := uptrend ? max - atrM : min + atrM
    [stop, uptrend]

[atrStop, uptrend] = st(src, length, factor)

plot(atrStop, "Volatility Stop", style=plot.style_stepline, color= uptrend ? #009688 : #F44336)
bool downtrend = (uptrend != true)


if (longCond )
    strategy.entry("BUY",strategy.long)
    
if (shortCond )
    strategy.entry("SELL",strategy.short)


tar=input(defval=30.0,title="TARGET IN POINTS")

sl=input(defval=30.0,title="STOP LOSS IN POINTS")
tar:=tar/syminfo.mintick
sl:=sl/syminfo.mintick

 //adding stoploss and target option
strategy.exit("x1", from_entry="BUY", qty = 50, profit = tar,loss = sl)

strategy.exit("x1", from_entry="SELL",qty = 50, profit = tar,loss = sl)


if crossunder(close,atrStop)
    strategy.close("BUY", qty_percent=100)
   

if crossover(close,atrStop)
    strategy.close("SELL",qty_percent=100)
    

strategy.exit(id="LX4",from_entry="BUY",qty_percent=100,loss=sl)
strategy.exit(id="LX4",from_entry="SELL",qty_percent=100,loss=sl)
```

Comment: Thanks you are awesome, also just wanted to know, if initial stoploss hits it exits all 100% position in 2 trades, is there way to exit it in a single order. i tried below code but unable to do it. //adding stoploss and target option
`strategy.exit("x1", from_entry="BUY", qty = 50, profit = tar)
strategy.exit("x2", from_entry="BUY", qty = 100, loss = sl)
strategy.exit("x3", from_entry="SELL",qty = 50, profit = tar)
strategy.exit("x4", from_entry="SELL",qty = 100, loss = sl)`